# Creating a new terminal/shell window to simply display text

Tags: python, shell

I want to pipe [edit: real-time text] the output of several subprocesses (sometimes chained, sometimes parallel) to a single terminal/tty window that is not the active python shell (be it an IDE, command-line, or a running script using tkinter). IPython is not an option. I need something that comes with the standard install.  Prefer OS-agnostic solution, but needs to work on XP/Vista.

I'll post what I've tried already if you want it, but it’s embarrassing.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like idle (the editor) does? Have a window behave like a stdout?

Comment: Are you launching the processes from a python script, or are you launching them from the command line and want to collect all the input into a python script you're working on?  Could you give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good solution in Unix would be named pipes.  I know you asked about Windows, but there might be a similar approach in Windows, or this might be helpful for someone else.

on terminal 1:

```
mkfifo /tmp/display_data
myapp >> /tmp/display_data
```

on terminal 2 (bash):

```
tail -f /tmp/display_data
```

**Edit**: *changed terminal 2 command to use "tail -f" instead of infinite loop.*

Answer (score 0):

You say "pipe" so I assume you're dealing with text output from the subprocesses.  A simple solution may be to just write output to files?

e.g. in the subprocess:

1. Redirect output `%TEMP%\output.txt`
2. On exit, copy `output.txt` to a directory your main process is watching.

In the main process:

1. Every second, examine directory for new files.
2. When files found, process and remove them.

You could encode the subprocess name in the output filename so you know how to process it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I plan to pipe stdout real-time for each process.  The file solution is workable, but my users are accustomed to a 30-60hz response time. I'm sure a HDD can handle it, but it seems unnecessary.  Also, I'm still unclear on how to spawn a shell-like window that only displays output text (separate from the current IDE / script-stdout) be it from a file or piped output.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a producer-customer system, where lines are inserted over a socket (nothing fancy here).
The customer would be a multithreaded socket server listening to connections and putting all lines into a **[Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)**. In the separate thread it would get items from the queue and print it on the console. The program can be run from the cmd console or from the eclipse console as an external tool without much trouble.

From your point of view, it should be realtime. As a bonus, You can place producers and customers on separate boxes. Producers can even form a network.

Some Examples of socket programming with python can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example). Look [here](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/echoserver.html) for an tcp echoserver example and [here](http://floppsie.comp.glam.ac.uk/Glamorgan/gaius/wireless/5.html) for a tcp "hello world" socket client.

There also is an extension for windows that enables usage of named pipes.

On linux (possibly cygwin?) You could just *tail -f named-fifo*.

Good luck!

Comment: +1:  This sounds very much like what I need.  I might eventually distribute these processes over a network in the future.
-1:  No references/examples.  (Google of "producer-customer system socket" is returning links to prosthetic manufacturing solutions ...and variations thereof are not very fruitful)

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It was `google python socket`, first result, then scroll down to the "examples" section. It seemed obvious to me, sorry about that. I have added some links to examples that might help You.

Comment: my search results return:
1st:
http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/issues/detail?id=68
2nd:
http://groups.google.com/group/project-voldemort/browse_thread/thread/2fc477c4c1e3fee9
3rd:
http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/sockets.html

Is the third the one you are referring to?   It seems the most useful, however none of them have an 'examples' section.   When you don't fully understand what you are looking for, it is not obvious when you have found it, and it is especially hard to determine if you have found a high-quality source.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example - I blame google. I have diffrent results than You.